# RMTrak Visual Basic Run Time Error 4248

Tags: vba, ms-word

When attempting to run RMTrak (a requirements mapping software), Visual Basic runtime error 4248 would appear. This only happens on a single file in the set of files being used. Other errors occur when attempting to run RMTrak while the document is currently open.

```
Run-time error '4248':
This command is not available because no document is open.
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813983 (1/6/2017)
```

How RMTrak works: RMTrak will open a file, parse it for specific formats, and consolidate it to their viewer. It will use tags inputted into the documents to relate to other other requirements, input specs, etc to show a list of requirements, their mapping, and how it relates.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the document in question and hit "Alt-F11". The VBA editor will appear. Either delete or comment out the VBA code. Save. Re-run.

When RMTrak is parsing the document, it is attempting to run the Visual Basic code that is embedded in the document. Since the document is not being opened by Word when RMTrak is parsing it, the "ActiveDocument" property is invalid.